# Make gwt website crawlable without hash symbol?

Tags: java, gwt, url-routing

In GWT we need to use **`#`** in a URL to navigate from one page to another i.e for creating history for eg. `www.abc.com/#questions/10245857` but due to which I am facing a problem in sharing the url. Google scrappers are reading the url only before `#` i.e. `www.abc.com`.

Now I want to remove `#` from my url and want to keep it straight as `www.abc.com/question/10245857`.

I am unable to do so.  How can I do this?

When user navigates the app I use the hash urls and History object (as
to not reload the pages). However sometimes it's nice/needed to have a
pretty URL (e.g. for sharing, showing in public, etc..) so I would like to know how to 
provide the pretty URL of the same page.

**Note:**
We have to do this to make our webpages url crawlable and to link the website with outside world.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are 3 issues here, and each can be solved:

1. The URL should appear prettier to the user
2. Going directly to the pretty URL should work.
3. WebCrawlers should be able to get the content

These may all seem like the same issue, but they are quite distinct in this context.

## Display Pretty URLs

Can be done with a small javascript file which uses [HTML5 state methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/API/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history). You can see a simple demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/24dofnv3/show/), with [source here](http://jsfiddle.net/24dofnv3/). This makes all changes to "#" appear without the "#" (on modern browsers).

Relevent code from fiddle:

```
var stateObj = {locationHash: hash};
history.replaceState(stateObj, "Page Title", baseURL + hash.substring(1));
```

## Repsond to Pretty URLs

This is relatively simple, as long as you have a listener in GWT to load based on the "#" at page load already. You can just throw up a simple re-direct servlet which reinserts the "#" mark where it belongs when requests come in.

For a servlet, listening for the pretty URL:

```
if(request.getPathInfo()!=null && request.getPathInfo().length()>1){
    response.sendRedirect("#" + request.getPathInfo());
    return;
}
```

Alternatively, you can serve up your GWT app directly from this servlet, and initialize it with parameters from the URL, but there's a bit of relative-path bookkeeping to be aware of.

## WebCrawlers

This is the trickiest one. Basically you can't get around having static(ish) pages here. That's not too hard if there are a finite set of simple states that you're indexing. One simple scheme is to have a separate servlet which returns the raw content you normally fetch with GWT, in minimal formatted HTML. This servlet can have a different URL pattern like "/indexing/". These wouldn't be meant for humans, just for the webcrawlers. You can attach a simple javascript in the <head> to redirect users to the pretty url once the page loads.

Here's an example for the doGet method of such a servlet:

```
response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
response.setStatus(200);
pw = response.getWriter();
pw.println("<html>");
pw.println("<head><script>");
pw.println("window.location.href='http://www.example.com/#"
        + request.getPathInfo() + "';");
pw.println("</script></head>");
pw.println("<body>");
pw.println(getRawPageContent(request.getPathInfo()));
pw.println("</body>");
pw.println("</html>");
pw.flush();
pw.close();
return;
```

You should then just have some links to these indexing pages hidden somewhere on your main app URL (or behind a link on your main app URL).